# Converting date from Hijri/Islamic Calendar to Georgian calendar

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, hijri

Im trying to convert a date in this format (1 بهمن 1397) into a Georgian calendar datetime. I'm using dateparser and I keep getting the type error: "'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'". This is the relevant part of the script:

```
date = HijriCalendar(u'24 دی 1397').get_date()
print(date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is not Hijri/Islamic date(Lunar), it is Iranian date(Solar) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iranian_calendars. You should search for persian/iranian/khorshidi/jalali calendars.

Khayyam3 is a library to use date & time in persian style(known as Jalali calendar or khayyam alg)
https://pypi.org/project/Khayyam3/

Comment: still can't convert it with that library - couldn't find a way to convert it from the format I have to datetime